# How to set message validity

Tags: ssl

I am using [Shibboleth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibboleth_%28Internet2%29) for single user authentication and it needs a ssl configuration which facilitates the user authentication process. Before it was working fine but now I am facing a **SSL handshake failure** error and the secure connection is being ignored.

**Error Log:**

Here is the Shibbolet error log:

```
2012-09-20 15:14:59 DEBUG Shibboleth.Listener [17]: dispatching message (default/SAML/POST)
2012-09-20 15:14:59 DEBUG OpenSAML.MessageDecoder.SAML1POST [17]: validating input
2012-09-20 15:14:59 DEBUG OpenSAML.MessageDecoder.SAML1POST [17]: decoded SAML response:
<Response xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:protocol" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" IssueInstant="2012-09-20T13:10:43.494Z" MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1" Recipient="https://inami-riziv.dokeosnet.com/Shibboleth.sso/SAML/POST" ResponseID="_faf482981786daacf938e158e87d75f8"><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"></ds:SignatureMethod>
<ds:Reference URI="#_faf482981786daacf938e158e87d75f8">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></ds:Transform>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="code ds kind rw saml samlp typens #default xsd xsi"></ec:InclusiveNamespaces></ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod>
<ds:DigestValue>qgvrV2yDB88HKXStzqT3sFrpLlo=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>
ifKK73UUbsOxqpsnfGcloErG5Vsrklckv/xpbsMAWDzrTm8ZvWjaLru0d7smEYmKFXdkJ/JayAXW
cM5aAKAwazWM7tj5YYvY3bTFlq4k/qI3GR46Kr5apGKkTEtDR9DkZDJ6N2+/vqOvdIxwefdFvaPs
FzsrZeGkt+IAcKmgCFZ78/2tbfckYd4sFGko0Lw3nIl9/dac03OJUsUVuScsiEVd6f/DjzedHgkk
3DD0xR2HFIY5MQzDdztz1f4PyuGFdXiyauUtm2bF+7XULQ8XwfGd+K0qIMOKBykTQuq0ijL+PpgZ
jRr3G2ylqSsJ1/NIwT6pRG79gJlcw55RB25XzA==
</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>
MIIE0DCCA7igAwIBAgILAQAAAAABMu4tWh8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwNDELMAkGA1UEBhMCQkUx
FjAUBgNVBAMTDUdvdmVybm1lbnQgQ0ExDTALBgNVBAUTBDIwMTAwHhcNMTExMDEwMTUwMTMyWhcN
MTMwMTEwMTUwMTMyWjCBrTEcMBoGA1UEAxMTQ0JFPTA4MDkzOTQ0MjcsIElBTTELMAkGA1UEBhMC
QkUxDDAKBgNVBAsTA0lBTTEXMBUGA1UECxMOQ0JFPTA4MDkzOTQ0MjcxGTAXBgNVBAsTEEVIRUFM
VEgtUExBVEZPUk0xITAfBgNVBAsTGGVIZWFsdGgtcGxhdGZvcm0gQmVsZ2l1bTEbMBkGA1UEChMS
RmVkZXJhbCBHb3Zlcm5tZW50MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAwgdTZNoR
CU7urB0+tdDDlVfrplxwcEwp+QoMJpiznNjMHZLxzwzl6PSMc8V7Gd2OGSGSHZJqrDz0643Djo6o
t59Tai2itHy9ZIQle3wmREi9ek86ousZuP6sZDw019xzztFLCaqO1Jfs28sBAeZovZZou7dDuD7w
86lkxvPssdJWZ0MO9FTwsseRoUowfWUfxp8E+3PpYdEy6BxGo5hh13lm2RphbcW0v0ouvR9yqVRh
cYhonol4Yj7nEm6tTc6NmCf2zEaX+F3e2hbj7bzgWJ1wKuhiMuQItLgN/XKhb6/jy44wjLj6IWIS
DH8LVPYITm+ImidDKI7WcGzJhu0IowIDAQABo4IBZzCCAWMwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUQZbOhaflXugW
WT0K8YTd8/K7TokwbgYIKwYBBQUHAQEEYjBgMDYGCCsGAQUFBzAChipodHRwOi8vY2VydHMucGtp
LmJlbGdpdW0uYmUvYmVsZ2l1bXJzMi5jcnQwJgYIKwYBBQUHMAGGGmh0dHA6Ly9vY3NwLnBraS5i
ZWxnaXVtLmJlMAkGA1UdEwQCMAAwRAYDVR0gBD0wOzA5BgdgOAkBAQMDMC4wLAYIKwYBBQUHAgEW
IGh0dHA6Ly9yZXBvc2l0b3J5LnBraS5iZWxnaXVtLmJlMD0GA1UdHwQ2MDQwMqAwoC6GLGh0dHA6
Ly9jcmwucGtpLmJlbGdpdW0uYmUvZ292ZXJubWVudDIwMTAuY3JsMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIE8DAR
BglghkgBhvhCAQEEBAMCBLAwHQYDVR0OBBYEFGtvDxQis8EQNHkujqvXW0CGhSbnMA0GCSqGSIb3
DQEBBQUAA4IBAQCDfqrhNJeB+tiesyXiAfuIwz2rJiVANb71VptyPGh96qMHBfU/w9fKdN87cF2J
IHg23ll0MEUo7I8oA2F5Dv0Jw/sB7GovOsosC6QcYzEo/D24vSYKI7Clw3SkKPUcqv3u68IPs8wF
L/Nowmxy6HGAvDlt1fQBpwePVKifGOygUcz0KWHMqNV7IJzyXrF2nbvg3TUJKaDR0zV4CjzLpaCI
IY1wY6e2/08mxf/Q5D7YO3sTxmjixkjRqCKXBCJa0CjXxT3/8Pfg5lHGNr7onIL84SMCZREur5I0
3u64HiqHBtSZaDWrw7d4CcjY/NoPfHO8hmAXEBMTm4zEhG4Nw0+2
</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature><Status><StatusCode Value="samlp:Success"></StatusCode></Status><Assertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" AssertionID="_56927407beba7fd1762d43bb15f71303" IssueInstant="2012-09-20T13:10:43.494Z" Issuer="http://idp.smals-mvm.be/shibboleth" MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1"><Conditions NotBefore="2012-09-20T13:10:43.494Z" NotOnOrAfter="2012-09-20T13:15:43.494Z"><AudienceRestrictionCondition><Audience>https://inami-riziv.dokeosnet.com/shibboleth</Audience><Audience>urn:be:fgov:ehealth:trust:partners</Audience></AudienceRestrictionCondition></Conditions><AuthenticationStatement AuthenticationInstant="2012-09-20T13:10:43.494Z" AuthenticationMethod="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:am:unspecified"><Subject><NameIdentifier Format="urn:mace:shibboleth:1.0:nameIdentifier" NameQualifier="http://idp.smals-mvm.be/shibboleth">_99e6f544a77e9b878ff54a1091c2c603</NameIdentifier><SubjectConfirmation><ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer</ConfirmationMethod></SubjectConfirmation></Subject><SubjectLocality IPAddress="193.191.246.82"></SubjectLocality></AuthenticationStatement></Assertion></Response>

2012-09-20 15:14:59 DEBUG OpenSAML.MessageDecoder.SAML1 [17]: extracting issuer from SAML 1.x Response
2012-09-20 15:14:59 DEBUG OpenSAML.MessageDecoder.SAML1 [17]: response from (http://idp.smals-mvm.be/shibboleth)
2012-09-20 15:14:59 DEBUG OpenSAML.MessageDecoder.SAML1 [17]: searching metadata for response issuer...
2012-09-20 15:14:59 DEBUG OpenSAML.SecurityPolicyRule.MessageFlow [17]: evaluating message flow policy (replay checking on, expiration 60)
2012-09-20 15:14:59 ERROR OpenSAML.SecurityPolicyRule.MessageFlow [17]: rejected expired message, timestamp (1348146643), oldest allowed (1348146659)
2012-09-20 15:19:53 INFO XMLTooling.StorageService : purged 1 expired record(s) from storage
2012-09-20 15:34:53 INFO XMLTooling.StorageService : purged 1 expired record(s) from storage
2012-09-20 15:42:06 DEBUG Shibboleth.Listener [18]: dispatching message (default::getHeaders::Application)
2012-09-20 15:42:06 DEBUG Shibboleth.Listener [18]: dispatching message (default/Login::run::Shib1SI)
2012-09-20 15:42:06 DEBUG XMLTooling.StorageService [18]: inserted record (9699add17fc90926f21c8fa06efec1e1) in context (RelayState) with expiration (1348149126)
2012-09-20 16:04:53 INFO XMLTooling.StorageService : purged 1 expired record(s) from storage
2012-09-20 16:19:53 INFO XMLTooling.StorageService : purged 2 expired record(s) from storage
2012-09-20 16:20:21 DEBUG Shibboleth.Listener [21]: dispatching message (default::getHeaders::Application)
2012-09-20 16:20:21 DEBUG Shibboleth.Listener [21]: dispatching message (default/Login::run::Shib1SI)
2012-09-20 16:20:21 DEBUG XMLTooling.StorageService [21]: inserted record (5bfae2fab27dfd8026a14e253696bc3a) in context (RelayState) with expiration (1348151421)
2012-09-20 16:34:53 INFO XMLTooling.StorageService : purged 1 expired record(s) from storage
2012-09-20 16:39:19 DEBUG Shibboleth.Listener [22]: dispatching message (default::getHeaders::Application)
2012-09-20 16:39:19 DEBUG Shibboleth.Listener [22]: dispatching message (default/Login::run::Shib1SI)
2012-09-20 16:39:19 DEBUG XMLTooling.StorageService [22]: inserted record (fbf6b65fc660ed134500345faef56f0a) in context (RelayState) with expiration (1348152559)
2012-09-20 16:43:29 INFO Shibboleth.Listener [15]: detected socket closure, shutting down worker thread
2012-09-20 16:49:53 INFO XMLTooling.StorageService : purged 1 expired record(s) from storage
2012-09-20 17:20:55 INFO Shibboleth.Listener [19]: detected socket closure, shutting down worker thread
2012-09-20 17:31:10 INFO Shibboleth.Listener [21]: detected socket closure, shutting down worker thread
2012-09-20 18:21:09 INFO Shibboleth.Listener [18]: detected socket closure, shutting down worker thread
2012-09-20 18:28:29 INFO Shibboleth.Listener [17]: detected socket closure, shutting down worker thread
2012-09-20 18:28:31 INFO Shibboleth.Listener [20]: detected socket closure, shutting down worker thread
2012-09-20 18:48:23 DEBUG Shibboleth.Listener [23]: dispatching message (default::getHeaders::Application)
2012-09-20 18:48:23 DEBUG Shibboleth.Listener [23]: dispatching message (default/Login::run::Shib1SI)
2012-09-20 18:48:23 DEBUG XMLTooling.StorageService [23]: inserted record (0b316ef6e5acf1da562899feb0b84ec1) in context (RelayState) with expiration (1348160303)
2012-09-20 18:52:26 DEBUG Shibboleth.Listener [24]: dispatching message (default::getHeaders::Application)
2012-09-20 18:52:26 DEBUG Shibboleth.Listener [24]: dispatching message (default/Login::run::Shib1SI)
2012-09-20 18:52:26 DEBUG XMLTooling.StorageService [24]: inserted record (b89fbe4deecae876148bd470e7aa6f85) in context (RelayState) with expiration (1348160546)
2012-09-20 18:52:38 DEBUG Shibboleth.Listener [25]: dispatching message (default::getHeaders::Application)
2012-09-20 18:52:38 DEBUG Shibboleth.Listener [25]: dispatching message (default/Login::run::Shib1SI)
2012-09-20 18:52:38 DEBUG XMLTooling.StorageService [25]: inserted record (b76b99286d06dd0ce84da39c9947e344) in context (RelayState) with expiration (1348160558)
2012-09-20 18:53:03 INFO Shibboleth.Listener [16]: detected socket closure, shutting down worker thread
2012-09-20 18:53:27 DEBUG Shibboleth.Listener [26]: dispatching message (default::getHeaders::Application)
2012-09-20 18:53:27 DEBUG Shibboleth.Listener [26]: dispatching message (default/Login::run::Shib1SI)
2012-09-20 18:53:27 DEBUG XMLTooling.StorageService [26]: inserted record (59fc5fa8d1589ffc94077f4e0e079f38) in context (RelayState) with expiration (1348160607)
2012-09-20 19:00:41 DEBUG Shibboleth.Listener [27]: dispatching message (default::getHeaders::Application)
2012-09-20 19:00:41 DEBUG Shibboleth.Listener [27]: dispatching message (default/Login::run::Shib1SI)
                                                                                                                              3865,1        99%
```

**What I understand From error log:**

The message is being expired when it reaches to the destination because the message validity is 5 min and i am in timezone 2+.

**My Question:**
How to set up message validity so that the message will remain valid and do not expire ?

Comment: [Reposted from Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20449/ssl-handshake-failure). [Please don't do that.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata/64073#64073) As you can see, it's caused essentially the same answer to be posted on both sites, as utopiabound could not have known that someone else had already proposed the same solution. In the future, please use the `flag` button and request that the question be migrated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both hosts have synced clocks.  I would recommend using `ntp`. The time zones shouldn't be an issue, you just need to make sure the clocks are synced.

Comment: Do you mean its problem due to clock slew ?

Comment: I had fixed the clock slew using [this tutorial](http://www.cydeweys.com/blog/2007/08/27/fixing-clock-skew-problems-in-gnulinux/) before.